# Count total number form Measure power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

In the power bi I have created a measure field which will count number of row

```
MeasureC = count([id_threshold])
```

How could I count percentage of MeasureC like

```
New_Measure% = MeasureC/Total(MeasureC)*100
```

or at least create a measure which will give me count Total like

```
 Total_measure = Sum(MeasureC)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
New_measure% = DIVIDE([MeasureC], CALCULATE([MeasureC],ALL(TableName)))
```

Replace `TableName` by the name of your table.

**UPDATE:** If `id_threshold` is row number column.

```
New_measure% = DIVIDE([MeasureC], CALCULATE(MAX([id_threshold]),ALL(TableName)))
```

or the total count measure is the MAX value of `id_threshold` column

```
Total count = CALCULATE(MAX([id_threshold]),ALL(TableName))
```

Comment: not really could you just help me how to create a measure to count  like (Total(MeasureC))

Comment: @Sumon, You can create the count total if you use a filter specifying that the calculation must be performed across the whole table not just in the given context. `Total Count=CALCULATE(COUNT([id_threshold]),ALL(TableContext))`